# Searching one to many database using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, normalization

I'm trying to construct a query that will allow me to pull a person with the defined attributes.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
TABLE: Person
+----------------------------------------------------+
owner_id | name
1        | kevin
2        | lee

+----------------------------------------------------+
TABLE: Attributes
+----------------------------------------------------+
id              | owner_id       | attributes_id
1               | 1              | 52
2               | 1              | 53
3               | 1              | 23
4               | 2              | 52


SELECT Person.name FROM Person LEFT JOIN `Attributes` ON `Attributes`.`owner_id` = `Person`.`owner_id` WHERE Attributes.attributes_id = 52 AND Attributes.attributes_id = 53;
```

Using that where clause didn't return the owner_id 1. If somebody could point me in the right direction I would be most greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Person.name 
FROM Person 
JOIN `Attributes` A1 ON A1.`owner_id` = `Person`.`owner_id` 
JOIN `Attributes` A2 ON A2.`owner_id` = `Person`.`owner_id` 
WHERE A1.attributes_id = 52 AND A2.attributes_id = 53;
```

I am presuming you want someone with all the attributes you list. I changed your left join to an inner join because it was that effectively anyway. You would have to join to the atrributes table separately for each attribute you require.

Another way is :

```
SELECT Person.name 
FROM Person 
JOIN `Attributes`  ON `Attributes`.`owner_id` = `Person`.`owner_id` 
WHERE `Attributes`.attributes_id = 52 OR `Attributes`.attributes_id = 53
GROUP BY Person.name 
Having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: i found that this solution is working better because the in clause will succeed even if a single attribute is true. So this is the best solution for this question. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're telling the database to find records where it is two different things at the same time. A single field can NOT **SIMULTANEOUSLY** be both `52` AND `53` at the same time. However, it can be one `OR` the other, so...

```
... WHERE Attributes.attributes_id = 52 OR Attributes.attributes_id = 53
or more succinctly
... WHERE Attributes.attributes_id IN (52, 53)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for helping me. I tried your query and the database returns 2 records for the same name. I put SELECT DISTINCT in my query and it returned one. Is that the right use for SELECT DISTINCT in my situation?

Comment: `select distinct` just ensures that you don't get any rows which are duplicates of any others.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with

```
WHERE Attributes.attributes_id = 52 AND Attributes.attributes_id = 53
```

change it to

```
WHERE Attributes.attributes_id in (52,53)
```